# Cross-platform Debian package testing

Tags: cross-platform, dpkg

I am trying to test Debian packages which are built on an x86 Linux system, but which will be executed on an ARM architecture.  My {pre,post}{inst,rm} scripts are failing with a "exec format error" because the /bin/bash in the chroot'd environment, which is an image of a flash filesystem, are ARM binaries, not x86 binaries.

What I'm looking for, but cannot find, is an option to dpkg which is like --root, but which doesn't use chroot.  I'd presumably need to know the name of some environmental variable (?) which contains the name of the parameter to --root.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to make the `/bin/bash` (and everything else) in the chroot executable.

Install `qemu-user-static` on the host. That will give you QEMU user space emulators for all architectures in static versions — so no complications with dynamic libraries in the chroot. It also configures binfmt support to execute ARM binaries with `/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static`.

Copy `/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static` into the `/usr/bin` of the chroot. Now you should be able to chroot and run programs normally. That way your Debian packages can be tested chrooted into their (emulated) native environment.

Comment: I'll take a look at this.  My "postinst" script has a bug, so I have to re-build the package anyway.  Look for an "^" and "v/" if things all work out.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the good suggestion to use `qemu`, starting with dpkg 1.18.5 you could use `--instdir` in conjunction with `--force-script-chrootless`. Depending on the maintainer scripts you might need to adapt them to make use of the `DPKG_ROOT` environment variable. There's more information in the `dpkg` man page.